# Having trouble making div responsive when window resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the theme, there's built-in responsive functions, everything in the body div or side-bar div will be resized accordingly... So I have installed a "RAW HTML" component on the body of this [following page](http://www.helpmyedu.com/unitest/).

Below is a screenshot of the page div I'm talking about:
[image]

This page works fine on my 19" screen, however when resized or viewed from a smaller screen like a laptop, the body div doesn't seem to resize even though I've already set the width to 100%..

What am I missing here?

Thanks alot!

Comment: it's not enough clear to solve your question.

Comment: you should use min-width parameter to #page div

Comment: Remove width: 890px; in .prods-cnt in your style.css. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this css

```
.prods-cnt {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    width: auto;//before it has width in px so change into auto or 100%
}
```

Comment: This was a fast answer!

Comment: However I ran into another issue, when I resized, the left hand side texts gets bumped down.... it'd be great if the div height can be reflexible, and the texts get wrapped in the div.